# Cant't get related models in django

Tags: django, django-models

My class:

```
class Image(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=30);
        date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True);
        image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', blank=True)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.title;
    
    
    class Comment(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        title = models.TextField(max_length=500);
        image=models.ForeignKey(Image, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

From Admin I add related comment to Image.
But when I watn get comments for Image, i get notfing

```
 images = Image.objects.get(id=pk)
    comments = images.comment_get.all()

    return render(request, 'images/image_view.html', {'image': images,'comments':comments})

   {% for comment in comments %}
            comment.title
       {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Notfing     {% for comment in comments %}
           {{ comment.title }}
       {% endfor %}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Related Managers

1. Default related managers are called by `model_set`
2. You may provide a custom related manager by adding in your `related='custom_related_name'` foreign key model
3. You may cancel the related manager automatic generation by adding `related='+'`

References:

[Related Objects Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference)

[Model Field Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

---

### View

```
def comments_view(request):
    payload = {
        'image': Image.objects.get(id=pk)
        'comments': payload['image'].comment_set.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'images/image_view.html', payload)
```

---

### Template

```
{% for data in images.comment_set.all %}
    {{ data.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

or

```
{% for comment in comments %}
    {{ comment.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: {% for data in image.comment_set.all %}
            {{ data.title }}
        {% endfor %}  -it work

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
comments = images.comment_set.all()
```

Comment: Notfing       comments = images.comment_set.all()

Comment: what? I don't understand word Notfing its not on the google either